# cross fade-in/fade-out images at one position with other images left to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prz9jm8x/9/embedded/result) in which there are **4 tiles** placed horizontally with some space in between.

Here is the CSS which I have used in order to place them horizontally.

```
.featured-block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve for the **3rd/4th tile(image)** in the fiddle is **I want cross-fade (fade-in/fade-out)** happen with **them(3rd/4th image)** at the **3rd position** from the **left**.

I believe I need to add the following css codes with some modification in order to make that happen but I am not sure what
modification I need to make.

```
.featured-block__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms ease; /* immediately start fading out when active class is lost */
}

.featured-block__item.featured-block__item-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following css code

```css
.featured-block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.featured-block__item:nth-last-child(2),
.featured-block__item:last-child{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms ease; /* immediately start fading out when active class is lost */
}
img{
  width:calc(100% / 3);
}
.featured-block__item:last-child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
 
  right: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  
  
}
.featured-block__item:nth-last-child(2).featured-block__item-active,
.featured-block__item:last-child.featured-block__item-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can update in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/prz9jm8x/9/ I tried your code in the fiddle but I am not getting the desired o/p.

Comment: i have updated fiddle, but i think the animation is showing in some other place.

Comment: Did you send the fiddle ?

Comment: have you got your desired o/p?